# Return value from callback function in AWS Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-js

I'm using the AWS Javascript SDK and I'm following the tutorial on how to send an SQS message. I'm basically following the [AWS tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/sqs-examples-send-receive-messages.html) which has an example of the `sendMessage` as follows:

```
sqs.sendMessage(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error", err);
  } else {
    console.log("Success", data.MessageId);
  }
});
```

So the `sendMessage` function uses a callback function to output whether the operation was successful or not. Instead of printing to the console I want to return a variable, but every value I set is only visible within the callback function, even global variables like `window.result` are not visible outside the callback function. Is there any way to return values outside the callback?

The only workaround I've found at the moment is to set a data attribute in an HTML element, but I don't think it's really elegant solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return value from an asynchronous callback function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-an-asynchronous-callback-function)

Comment: The problem is not visibility but timing. Surely, a global variable is visible globally. What happens in your case is that you you try to access a variable _before_ it is assigned a value, because the callback function executes later in time.

Comment: @marekful, agreed the question has been asked already, but the accepted answer is from 2011.  Fortunately, JS evolved a bit and allow for cleaner solutions today.

Comment: @Vasilis, sorry linked the wrong one. Click through its duplicate and check answers there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use `Promises` and the new `async` and `await` keywords in ES2016.  It makes your code so much easier to read.

```
async function sendMessage(message) {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        // TODO be sure SQS client is initialized
        // TODO set your params correctly 
        const params = {
            payload : message
        };

        sqs.sendMessage(params, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Error when calling SQS");
                console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(data);
            }
        });         
    });
}

// calling the above and getting the result is now as simple as :
const result = await sendMessage("Hello World");
```

Comment: it could've been just `try { const result = await sqs.sendMessage({..}).promise() } catch (err) throw err }` but OP is trying to implement it in browser and not all browsers support async await syntax.